# Loop same macro code across selected worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm new to excel VBA. I'm looking for some guidance for running the same macro (Excel Solver) to certain worksheets. The Excel Solver works, however, I can't get the looping to apply to the different worksheets.

```
Sub MLoop()
Dim xsheet As Worksheet

For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If xsheet.Name = "ABC" And "CDE" and "FGH" Then

xsheet.Select

Dim Target_Range_Address As String
Dim Change_Cell_Address As String
Dim Total_Column As Integer

Total_Column = 30

For i = 0 To Total_Column - 1

    Target_Range_Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 6 + i).Address
    Change_Cell_Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 6 + i).Address

        SolverOk SetCell:=Target_Range_Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Change_Cell_Address, Engine:=1 _
            , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve (True)
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i
End
Next xsheet

End Sub
```

Appreciate the help! thanks.

Comment: `If xsheet.Name = "ABC" And "CDE" and "FGH" Then` does not have any meaning for VBA. Try, please `If xsheet.Name = "ABC" Or  xsheet.Name = "CDE" Or  xsheet.Name = "FGH" Then`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgotten the "End If"! Code below works now :)

```
Sub MLoop()
Dim xsheet As Worksheet

For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If xsheet.Name = "ABC" Or xsheet.Name = "CDE" Or xsheet.Name = "FGH" Then

xsheet.Select

Dim Target_Range_Address As String
Dim Change_Cell_Address As String
Dim Total_Column As Integer

Total_Column = 30

For i = 0 To Total_Column - 1

    Target_Range_Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(6, 6 + i).Address
    Change_Cell_Address = ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 6 + i).Address

        SolverOk SetCell:=Target_Range_Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Change_Cell_Address, Engine:=1 _
            , EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
        SolverSolve (True)
        SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

Next i
End if
Next xsheet

End Sub
```